# CSS position fixed property error

Tags: css, position, width, fixed

This is my website :  http://www.kursatkarabulut.com/dersler/

I'm trying to make the like buttons stay on a fixed position on top left of the browser.
Each like button is in another child class of .likebuttons. What is wrong with this CSS?

My CSS is :

```
.likebuttons {
    position:fixed;
    left:5px;
    top:5px;
    margin:20px 25px 0;
}
```

Also I have another question. Page width is 800px. When I open this page in Explorer/Opera/Safari/Mozilla It all seems normal. But when I open it in Chrome, it ignores width:800px; and margin:0 auto; to become full screen wide. How can I fix this?

My HTML is:

```
body {
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    text-align:justify;
    padding: auto;
    background:#CCCCCC;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong? The buttons does stay fixed in the top left corner in my firefox browser and the page is 800 pixels in my chrome. Have you updated your site?

Comment: I've updated the website but I don't know why it still happens. Buttons roll with the page too no matter which browser I use. I was using Cloudflare and disabled it thinking that maybe it causes problems.

Comment: That's odd. They stand still both in my firefox and google-chrome. Are you testing on mobile devices? Mobile browsers seems to handle position:fixed quite different from other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you have :

```
.likebuttons {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 20px 25px 0;
    clear: right;
}
```

Change `top: 100px;` to `top: 0px;`

Works normal in chrome.